# Formatting issue in D3

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am having a formatting issue with a d3 graphical representation.
The X axis is entered in years, which I thought would be easier to treat as any other number (instead of as dateFormat... %Y )
The output is automatically (?) adds the comma for the thousandths place- my assumption.
Is there a way to keep this the 4 dig int that it is?

(this is my first foray into HTML, CSS, JS and d3-- thank you for empathy/comments)
Thanks.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    
    body { font: 12px Arial;}
    
    path { 
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 2;
        fill: none;
    }
    
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: grey;
        stroke-width: 1;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    
    </style>
    <body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
    
    var margin = {top: 30, right: 40, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
    
    var  x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
    var y0 = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
    var y1 = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
    
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
        .orient("bottom").ticks(5);
    
    var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis().scale(y0)
        .orient("left").ticks(5);
    
    var yAxisRight = d3.svg.axis().scale(y1)
        .orient("right").ticks(5); 
    
    var valueline = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.year); })
        .y(function(d) { return y0(d.freq); });
        
    var valueline2 = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.year); })
        .y(function(d) { return y1(d.fn); });
      
    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
            .attr("transform", 
                  "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
    // Get the data
    d3.csv("duallines2.csv", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.year = +(d.year);
            d.freq = +d.freq;
            d.fn = +d.fn;
        });
    
        // Scale the range of the data
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; }));
        y0.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
            return Math.max(d.freq); })]); 
        y1.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { 
            return Math.max(d.fn); })]);
    
        svg.append("path")        // Add the valueline path.
            .attr("d", valueline(data));
    
        svg.append("path")        // Add the valueline2 path.
            .style("stroke", "red")
            .attr("d", valueline2(data));
    
        svg.append("g")            // Add the X Axis
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);
    
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .style("fill", "steelblue")
            .call(yAxisLeft);   
    
        svg.append("g")             
            .attr("class", "y axis")    
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + " ,0)")   
            .style("fill", "red")       
            .call(yAxisRight);
    
    });
    
    </script>
    </body>
```

The datafile looks like this:

## "duallines2.csv"

year,freq,fn
1950,58.13,3.41
1951,53.98,4.55
1952,67.00,6.78
1953,89.70,7.85
1954,99.00,8.92
1955,130.28,9.92
1956,166.70,10.13
1957,234.98,12.23
1958,345.44,13.45
1959,443.34,16.04
1960,543.70,18.03
1961,580.13,21.02
1962,605.23,22.34
1963,622.77,20.15
1964,626.20,21.26
1965,628.44,31.04
1966,636.23,35.04
1967,633.68,41.02
1968,624.31,43.05
1969,629.32,46.03
1970,618.63,51.03
1971,599.55,53.42
1973,609.86,57.82
1974,617.62,59.01
1975,614.48,56.03
1976,606.98,58.01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own `format` -- in this case making each `xAxis` tick label an integer -- and then tell the `xAxis` to use that `format`:

```
var format = d3.format("d");
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(5)
    .tickFormat(format); // <----- tell the xAxis to use your custom formatter
```

And here's the updated output you'll get:

[image: graph with proper x-axis labels]

See the docs on formatting numbers [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting#d3_format).

Comment: this is very helpful! Getting started is hard-- but/and every step teaches me something. It's quite fun. Thanks again

Comment: So now a graph works! The data come from a python script; I've put the query to it from php in my html. Can you put me in the right direction to figure out how to bring the data back into the html page and render the graphic on the webpage?    Thanks

Comment: @Pathgeek: Not sure I understand, perhaps ask another StackOverflow question so other users can help and/or find an answer more easily?